# Как устранить циклическую переадресацию страницы?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть интернет-магазин на `wordpress+woocommerce`, в котором есть проблема при переходе в пустую корзину - страница перехода зацикливается и выдает соответствующую ошибку. Если положить хоть 1 товар, то зацикливания не происходит и все отрабатывает норм. В настройках корзины выбрана страница личного кабинета установленного плагина [Theme My Login](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-my-login/), в котором добавлен шорткод корзины. В чем может быть причина и как это можно увидеть и исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение! Вся фишка в том, что если на одной странице расположены шорткоды корзины и оформления, то при пустой корзине (если переходить на страницу оформления срабатывает редирект), таким образом получается циклический редирект.
Исправляется в функции wc_template_redirect(), который расположен в

```
\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php
```

удаляется вот этот кусок

```
  // When on the checkout with an empty cart, redirect to cart page
   elseif ( is_page( wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' ) ) && sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) == 0 && empty( $wp->query_vars['order-pay'] ) && ! isset( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
     wp_redirect( get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) );
     exit;
   }
```

подробно объясняется с решением на форуме [тут](http://wpcommerce.ru/threads/sovmeschenie-korziny-i-oplaty-v-oformlenie-zakaza.257/page-2#post-4069)

Comment: upvote это же вордпресс...

Comment: С решениэм понятно. Но остается вопрос, как обнавление этого плагина будет происходит после?

Comment: @E_p можно переопределять функцию через `functions.php` - по ссылке выше об этом рассказывается или воспользоваться платным плагином - там же